# ansible parsing json into include_tasks loop

Tags: json, linux, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have the following json file called cust.json :

```
{
 "customer":{
        "CUST1":{
                "zone":"ZONE1",
                "site":"ASIA"
        },
       "CUST2":{
                "zone":"ZONE2",
                "site":"EUROPE"
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this json file in my main.yml to get a list of customers (CUST1 and CUST2).

`main.yml`:

```
- name: Include the vars
  include_vars:
    file: "{{ playbook_dir }}/../default_vars/cust.json"
    name: "cust_json"

- name: Generate customer config 
  include_tasks: create_config.yml
  loop: "{{ cust_json.customer }}"
```

I was hoping the loop will basically pass each customer's code (eg CUST1) to `create_config.yml`, so that something like the following can happen:

`create_config.yml`:

```
- name: Create customer config 
  block:
    - name: create temporary file for customer
      tempfile:
        path: "/tmp"
        state: file
        prefix: "my customerconfig_{{ item }}."
        suffix: ".tgz"
      register: tempfile

    - name: Setup other things
      include_tasks: "othercustconfigs.yml"
```

Which will result in :

1. The following files being generated : `/tmp/mycustomerconfig_CUST1` and `/tmp/mycustomerconfig_CUST2`
2. The tasks within `othercustconfigs.yml` be run for CUST1 and CUST2.

Questions :

1. Running the ansible, it fails at this point:

```
TASK [myrole : Generate customer config ] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************

fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: {u'CUST1': {u'site': u'ASIA', u'zone': u'ZONE1'}, u'CUST2': {u'site': u'EUROPE', u'zone': uZONE2'}}. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."
}
```

How do I loop the JSON so that it would get the list of customers (CUST1 and CUST2) correctly? `loop: "{{ cust_json.customer }}"` clearly doesnt work.

2. If I manage to get the above working, is it possible to pass the result of the loop to the next `include_tasks: "othercustconfigs.yml` ? SO basically, passing the looped items from `main.yml` , then to `config.yml`, and then to `othercustconfigs.yml`. Is this possible?

Thanks!!
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cust_json.customer` is a hashmap containing one key for each customer, not a list.

The `dict2items` filter can transform this hashmap into a list of elements each containing a `key` and `value` attribute, e.g:

```yaml
- key: "CUST1"
  value:
    zone: "ZONE1"
    site: "ASIA"
- key: "CUST2"
  value:
    zone: "ZONE2"
    site: "EUROPE"
```

With this in mind, you can transform your include to the following:

```yaml
- name: Generate customer config 
  include_tasks: create_config.yml
  loop: "{{ cust_json.customer | dict2items }}"
```

and the relevant task in your included file to:

```yaml
    - name: create temporary file for customer
      tempfile:
        path: "/tmp"
        state: file
        prefix: "my customerconfig_{{ item.key }}."
        suffix: ".tgz"
      register: tempfile
```

Of course you can adapt all this to use the `value` element where needed, e.g. `item.value.site`

You can see the following documentations for in depth info and alternative solutions:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#iterating-over-a-dictionary
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-dict
- https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#dictsort

Comment: This works perfectly as u had suggested, thanks so much. The links are very useful. Thanks again